# How to configure access to shiny application logs?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I was trying to record all logs of my shiny applications.
Checking in /var/log/shiny-server I could see that there are few logs and the last one is from 2019-10-10. After that date, there are no more.
I tried to add preserve_logs to shiny-server.config but I didn't have any changes.
My shiny-server.config looks like this

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

preserve_logs true;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

  # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
  site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

  # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
  log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

  # when a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
  # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
  directory_index on;
  }
}
```

Comment: Two questions, 1. why is your `site_dir` pointing to your log folder? and 2. are you sure you've actually been getting errors in your apps?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong on site_dir. I edited it for the form in my file.
When the other question, yes I forced some errors to see if it would generate any new logs and did not.